# Unable to load multiple json files with pandas

Tags: python, json, pandas, glob, kaggle

I am trying to load all JSON files from various subdirectories of /kaggle/input/CORD-19-research-challenge/.

Please refer the notebook (committed the latest changes): https://www.kaggle.com/psrajput/cord-19/

```
for file in glob.glob('/kaggle/input/CORD-19-research-challenge/**/*.json', recursive=True):
    data = pd.read_json(file)
    temp = pd.DataFrame().append(data)
```

And getting the following error:

***ValueError***: arrays must all be the same length

Comment: 1) What is the full traceback? 2) `temp = pd.DataFrame().append(data)` seems redundant `data` should already be a `DataFrame` object returned by `pd.read_json(file)`. If you are just trying to have a copy of the df assigned to `temp` then use `pandas.DataFrame.copy`.

Comment: @Phillyclause89 There are multiple json files in 4 different folders. I want them to be in a single pandas dataframe.

Comment: `temp = pd.DataFrame().append(data)` is just trying to append your data to an empty df returned by the `pd.DataFrame()` part. What I would do is inititliaze `temp` as an empty `list` (`temp = []`) before you enter the `for` loop. Then replace `temp = pd.DataFrame().append(data)` with just `temp.append(data)` (note the list.append is an inplace method). Once you exit your loop, uses `pd.concat(temp)` to join all the DataFrames in your 'temp' list.

Comment: @Phillyclause89 You meant something like this? Still the same error.

```
dataset = []
for file in glob.glob('/kaggle/input/CORD-19-research-challenge/**/*.json', recursive=True):
    data = pd.read_json(file)
    dataset.append(data)
    
pd.concat(dataset)
```

Comment: I [forked](https://www.kaggle.com/philipalexanderlees/kernela990a37deb?scriptVersionId=30935180) your Kaggle notebook and played around with the part of your code that was causing the issue. It looks like the JSON data is too complex to be easily loaded into a `pandas.DataFrame`. The only way I could get it to work was by using  `pd.read_json(file, orient='index')` and the resulting df is likely not what you are looking for. I think what you'll need to do is use the json module to load the files and build the df using the info you want using specific keys.

Comment: Here is an [updated link to my fork of your Kaggle notebook](https://www.kaggle.com/philipalexanderlees/kernela990a37deb?scriptVersionId=30941074#3.-Loading-Data-with-Pandas-as-Dataframes-). In it is an example of how you could make a two column `DataFrame` of just the paper ids and the body texts.